# Nagios notification when no message is received within 48 hours

Tags: nagios

In `Nagios` it is easy to check that a `LogMessage` happened in the last 48 hours and sound an alarm. What I would like, though, is to instead configure `Nagios` to sound an alarm when a specific message *did not* occur within 48 hours.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I am using the "Check WMI Plus" plugin (no agent required) in order to check the event log on a windows box.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what your exact "specific message" is, it's hard to give a specific answer, but we can do this:

I'm going to raise a CRITICAL event when I haven't seen a "processing of windows Group Policy failed" error or warning event in the last 48 hours.

You use the -w and -c options to define criteria for WARNING and CRITICAL events in check_wmi_plus.

From `check_wmi_plus.pl --help | less -i` we get the help and we can find the checkeventlog options.

There are two tricks:

1. checkeventlog only has one field _ItemCount, so you don't need to specify it
2. You want to specify a
   range of values, that includes only 0 - so use `@0:0`

First, define a specific section in the events.ini file. Mine is: `/opt/nagios/bin/plugins/check_wmi_plus.d/events.ini`

I added this:

```
[eventSpecial]

im=Group Policy failed
```

I added that just below the [eventdefault] section.

Basically, the `im=` means 'include message' - if it's not specified everything is included, so by specifying it, I've said "only include messages that match this regular expression."

Then you need the command for checkeventlog

I use:

```
/opt/nagios/bin/plugins/check_wmi_plus.pl -H HOST -u USER -p PASS  -m checkeventlog -a % -o 2 -3 48 -4 eventSpecial -c @0:0
```

So for the optional arguments (again with the --help option):

-a %              == search all event logs

-o 2              == Warning and error severity only

-3 48             == last 48 hours

-4 eventSpecial   == refer to the section in events.ini that I just created

-c @0:0           == raise a CRITICAL if there are exactly 0 occurances

With this command, if there ARE messages during the period, I get:

> OK - 3 event(s) of Severity Level: "Error,Warning", were recorded in
>   the last 48 hours from the % Event Log. (List is on next line. Fields
>   shown are -
>   Logfile:TimeGenerated:SeverityLevel:EventId:Type:SourceName:Message)|'Event
>   Count'=3;0; 
>   System:20130604195600.378642-000|Error:1129:0:Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy:The processing of Group Policy failed because of lack of network
>   connectivity to a domain controller. This may be a transient
>   condition. A success message would be generated once the machine gets
>   connected to the domain controller and Group Policy has succesfully
>   processed. If you do not see a success message for several hours, then
>   contact your administrator.
>   System:20130604055521.084809-000|Error:1129:0:Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy:The processing of Group Policy failed because of lack of network
>   connectivity to a domain controller. This may be a transient
>   condition. A success message would be generated once the machine gets
>   connected to the domain controller and Group Policy has succesfully
>   processed. If you do not see a success message for several hours, then
>   contact your administrator.
>   System:20130603220259.894040-000|Error:1055:0:Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy:The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not resolve the
>   computer name. This could be caused by one of more of the following:
>   a) Name Resolution failure on the current domain controller.   b)
>   Active Directory Replication Latency (an account created on another
>   domain controller has not replicated to the current domain
>   controller).

Which does not include a critical event.

If there are none, I get this:

> CRITICAL - [Triggered by _ItemCount in the range 0:0] - 0 event(s) of
>   Severity Level: "Error,Warning", were recorded in the last 4 hours
>   from the % Event Log.|'Event Count'=0;0;

Which does include the critical event, because there were no entries in the log file to match my criteria.

And you can just define a standard Nagios command using the appropriate $USER8$ macros to include it in your configuration.

Answer (score -2):

You should try this and create a simple DOS script that is kicked off every hour to monitor nagios and restart it when it see 2 nagios.exe. Here is the DOS script to kill the nagios.exe service and restart it.

-------- CheckNagios.bat --------

```
@echo off
set mypgm=nagios.exe

REM GET date/time stamp
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a%%b)

:checkNagios
rem get number of nagios processes
for /f %%i in ('c:\windows\system32\tasklist.exe ^| find /i /c "%mypgm%"') do set /a numProc=%%i

echo Last Check: %mydate%_%mytime%

ECHO # of processes = %numProc%

if %numProc% GTR 1. (goto kill) else goto end

:kill
c:\windows\system32\taskkill.exe /f /IM %mypgm%

REM restart nagios
net start Nagwin_Nagios

REM restart other nagios processes
rem for /f %%x in ('net start ^| findstr /i "nagwin_"') do net stop %%x

:end
echo Exiting program.
echo =================

rem SCHEDULE TASK TO RUN EVERY HOUR and pipe to a logfile
rem SCHTASKS /create /TN "Check Nagios" /TR "c:\icw\bin\checkNagios.bat >> c:\checknagios.log 2>&1" /SC HOURLY /ST 16:00 /MO 1 /RU DOMAIN\USERNAME /RP PASSWORD

REM store last check that will be used by emailNagios.bat using blat.exe
set LAST_NAGIOS_CHECK=%%mydate%%_%%mytime%%
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: this is a script so that nagios cheks massages every hour and not every 48h so the chance of losing a massage is almost impossible.